# Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python-2.7

I am having issues with my python code. The funny thing is this code currently runs on 2 raspberry pis and was wondering why it is not running on a new one.

Its basic just to display the text on the 16x02 LCD.

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import time
import MFRC522
from RPLCD import CharLCD
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
from datetime import datetime
gpio.setwarnings(False)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
MIFAREReader = MFRC522.MFRC522()
gpio.setwarnings(False)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(11, gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(37, gpio.OUT)


lcd = CharLCD(cols=16, rows=2,

                pin_rw=None,

                pin_rs=38,

                pin_e=36,

                pins_data=[10,12,16,18],

                numbering_mode=gpio.BOARD
)

lcd.cursor_pos=(0,0)
lcd.write_string("Attendance ")
lcd.cursor_pos=(1,0)
lcd.write_string("Already Taken")                            
time.sleep(2)
lcd.clear()
lcd.write_string('Scanning ...')
```

But it is giving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29 in <module>
    numbering_mode=gpio.BOARD
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

Comment: Well formated question (edit your output snapshot into the question - that is the preferred way to display errors/exceptions). Welcome to SO mate!